# Are there 2 ways to JOIN a table on SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have this discipline on Uni (over internet) and they asked to build a `SELECT` with `JOIN`.

As I have some knowledge about `JOIN` I tried to build the query without checking the apostille, but after I checked I saw that they are teaching somehow different.

Is it ok to do both ways or is there a "newer" version that I should always use?
The discipline is about `Postgresql` and I'm used to use `MySQL`.

Query that I'm used to:

```
SELECT Cliente.nome, Endereco.rua, Endereco.nro, Endereco.complement
    FROM Cliente
    JOIN Endereco
        ON Endereco.Cod_end = Cliente.Cod_end
    JOIN Pedido
        ON Pedido.Cod_Cliente = Cliente.Codigo
    WHERE Pedido.data = “02/01/16”;
```

Query that is in the apostille:

```
SELECT Cliente.nome, Endereco.rua, Endereco.nro, Endereco.complement
    FROM Cliente, Endereco, Pedido
    Where Endereco.Cod_end = Cliente.Cod_end
        AND Pedido.Cod_Cliente = Cliente.Codigo
        AND Pedido.data = “02/01/16”;
```

Comment: The "apostille" is wrong.  Your first method is the correct way to write joins, using explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax.  It has been the correct way for decades.

Comment: BTW: in both case the date literal should be quoted with single quotes : `AND Pedido.data = '02/01/16';` , double quotes are used to quote identifiers. And mot people prefer iso style date-literals : `AND Pedido.data = '2016-02-01';`

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks! I thought that there was some difference between `MySQL` and `Postgresql` but it seems they didn't update the apostille (i'm not sure if it's the correct name in english lol).

Comment: @wildplasser, thanks for pointing out! I saw the single quotes on the apostille, but I wasn't sure about that. I notice the format too, but in there they are querying it as `'02/01/16'` instead `'2016-02-01'` so I guess I'll leave it as the first one to not lose any marks.

Comment: As defined by ANSI/ISO SQL, date literals are written in this format: **DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'**. I haven't seen yet a database that doesn't support this notation.

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . SQL Server and MySQL come to mind.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, **wrong** about **MySQL** - `select date_add(date '2016-10-31',interval 1 day) /* 2016-11-01 */`, **right** about **SQL Server** - I thought they had already clean their dates' mess.